# Are there any power consumption indicators?

Tags: unity, power-management, indicator, battery

I would love to see how much power my notebook is consuming all the time.

Therefore I want an indicator that constantly (interval of 1 second maybe) monitors the current power consumption (electric current measured in mA or electric power measured in W) and displays it in my Unity panel of Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Will begin writing one tonight ;) Very easy to make

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note:** *As of right now it is not possible to measure power consumption of laptop on AC adapter or a desktop computer via software means. Even other OS such as windows requires having external hardware sensors to provide that information. If you want indicator for desktop computer , this answer won't work for you*

I have written an indicator that monitors energy consumption in both Watts and milli - Amps. The usage if very simple :

```
 python /path/to/power-flow-indicator
```

or  from the same directory as the script:

```
 ./power-flow-indicator
```

By default output is shown in Watts, but `--amps` option allows showing the output in milli-amps:

```
python power-flow-indicator --amps
```

The `-h` will show this same information :

```
usage: power-flow-indicator [-h] [--amps]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  --amps      display output in milliamps
```

#### Obtaining the Indicator

The indicator source code is located on [GitHub](https://github.com/SergKolo/power-flow-indicator). If you have `git` installed , you can clone the repository via:

```
git clone https://github.com/SergKolo/power-flow-indicator.git
```

Alternatively , one can obtain zip file via

```
 wget https://github.com/SergKolo/power-flow-indicator/archive/master.zip
```

#### Source Code

**NOTE**: the indicator needs an icon. It is preferable that you clone the git repository or obtain the zip package rather than just copying the source code alone.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#
# Author: Serg Kolo , contact: 1047481448@qq.com
# Date: July 21, 2012
# Purpose: Indicator that displays power  
#          consumption of  laptop battery
#
# Written for: http://askubuntu.com/q/801003/295286
# Tested on: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
#
#
#
# Licensed under The MIT License (MIT).
# See included LICENSE file or the notice below.
#
# Copyright © 2016 Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy
#
# Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
# of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
# in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
# to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
# copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
# furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
#
# The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included
# in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
#
# THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
# IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
# FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
# AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
# LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
# OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE
# SOFTWARE.
import gi
gi.require_version('AppIndicator3', '0.1')
from gi.repository import GLib as glib
from gi.repository import AppIndicator3 as appindicator
from gi.repository import Gtk as gtk
import os
import dbus
import subprocess
import argparse

class LockKeyStatusIndicator(object):

    def __init__(self, show_amps):
        self.show_amps = show_amps
        self.app = appindicator.Indicator.new(
            'power-flow-indicator', "",
            appindicator.IndicatorCategory.APPLICATION_STATUS)

        self.app.set_status(appindicator.IndicatorStatus.ACTIVE)
        self.icon_path = os.path.dirname( os.path.realpath(__file__) )
        self.app.set_icon( os.path.join(self.icon_path,"pwi_icon.png"  ))

        self.update_label()
        self.app_menu = gtk.Menu()
        self.quit_app = gtk.MenuItem('Quit')
        self.quit_app.connect('activate', self.quit)
        self.quit_app.show()
        self.app_menu.append(self.quit_app)

        self.app.set_menu(self.app_menu)

    def run(self):

        try:
            gtk.main()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass

    def quit(self, data=None):

        gtk.main_quit()

    def run_cmd(self, cmdlist):

        new_env = dict( os.environ ) 
        new_env['LC_ALL'] = 'C' 
        try:
            stdout = subprocess.check_output(cmdlist,env=new_env)
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
            pass
        else:
            if stdout:
                return stdout

    def run_dbus_method(self, bus_type, obj, path, interface, method, arg):

        if bus_type == "session":

            bus = dbus.SessionBus()

        if bus_type == "system":

            bus = dbus.SystemBus()

        proxy = bus.get_object(obj, path)
        method = proxy.get_dbus_method(method, interface)

        if arg:

            return method(arg)

        else:

            return method()

    def get_power_info(self):

        battery_path = None
        battery_info = []
        energy_rate = None
        voltage = None
        current = None
        on_battery = None

        for line in self.run_cmd(['upower', '-e']).decode().split('\n'):
            if 'battery_BAT' in line:
                battery_path = line
                break
        self.run_dbus_method('system', 'org.freedesktop.UPower',
                             battery_path, 'org.freedesktop.UPower.Device',
                             'Refresh', 'None')

        for entry in self.run_cmd(
                ['upower', '-i', battery_path]).decode().split('\n'):
            if 'state' in entry:
                if entry.replace(" ", "").split(':')[1] == 'discharging':
                    on_battery = True
            if 'energy-rate' in entry:
                energy_rate = entry.replace(" ", "").split(':')[1][:-1]
                print energy_rate
            if 'voltage' in entry:
                voltage = entry.replace(" ", "").split(':')[1]

        current = round(
            1000 * float(energy_rate[:-1]) / float(voltage[:-1]), 4)

        if on_battery:
            return str(round(float(energy_rate),2)) + 'W', str(int(current)) + 'mA'
        else:
            return 'on ac', 'on ac'

    def update_label(self):

        cwd = os.getcwd()
        red_icon = os.path.join(cwd, 'red.png')
        green_icon = os.path.join(cwd, 'green.png')
        if self.show_amps:
            label_text = self.get_power_info()[1]
        else:
            label_text = self.get_power_info()[0]

        self.app.set_label(label_text, "")
        glib.timeout_add_seconds(1, self.set_app_label)

    def set_app_label(self):

        self.update_label()


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        "--amps", help="display output in milliamps", action="store_true")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    indicator = LockKeyStatusIndicator(args.amps)
    indicator.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```