# How to get the current (in mA) laptop battery is draining from the charger?

Tags: laptop, battery, overheating

I bought a new battery and a new charger recently, and since then the charger has been constantly overheating. I wonder if there is a way to figure out the current battery is trying to get from the charger. I know that the "Details" section of the battery menu shows "Rate" in watts, but I guess this is the rate at which laptop is draining battery, right?

Comment: See  https://askubuntu.com/a/801635/295286  I've written that a while ago, and the indicator shows current usage, but that may have been added in newer version, which is on github.  https://github.com/SergKolo/power-flow-indicator   Le me know if that helps

Comment: Ah, I see. You're asking the current flow from charger to battery. That I'm afraid is impossible to measure, unless there's internal circuitry for that between power supply and battery. So, I guesa the answer to the question is "not possible".

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy ok, but still, thank you for finding time to reply!

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy You can jerry-rig an amperage meter between the wall outlet and the charger plug I guess. Also my UPS shows current drain and estimated life span. I could plug my laptops charger into the UPS and get real-time stats via USB interface. Minner--Is the laptop running whilst the battery is charging? That should be good for ~60-100 watts. Then the battery charge rate itself can be set to trickle or fast charge depending on BIOS. That adds varying amount of watts.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Yeah, that's kinda what I was saying before, it requires having something in between the battery and charger.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix yep, I was thinking of plugging the charger to the wall through the amperemeter

Comment: @Minner That's probably not gonna be accurate. Power supplies have transformers. Current differs between primary and secondary winding. Source: I'm kinda electrical engineering student.